# Open file with installed app

Tags: android, file

I need a help. I was trying a lot of things, but no one worked. I want to open an .txt file from sdcard. So I want to open some app like a Es File Exprorer or And Explorer and select the file and open it. This is my code:

```
public class Open extends Activity {


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri startDir = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard"));
        intent.setDataAndType(startDir, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andexplorer.file");


}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run that? Typically a good idea to include logcat information or what happens when you attempt what you are trying.

Comment: In this case it is not doing anything. But I tried a lot of combinations of code and app was crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and see what happens.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("/sdcard/mytextfile.txt");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Where `mytextfile.txt` is replaced by your file name.